# EXCEL - Formula to sum total period of multiple durations without duplicating overlapping time periods

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

```
Machine_ID  STARTDATE   ENDDATE
Machine 1   23-Apr-10   8-Jul-13
Machine 1   16-Jun-10   10-Jul-10
Machine 1   15-Aug-12   5-Oct-12
Machine 1   9-Jul-13    2-Jan-14
Machine 1   31-Dec-13   3-Jan-14
Machine 2   28-Mar-13   14-Apr-13
Machine 2   12-Jun-13   27-Jul-13
Machine 2   24-Jul-13   28-Oct-13
Machine 2   24-Oct-13   27-Oct-13
```

I want to calculate the total time by each machine without duplicating overlapping time periods. So far this array formula (ctrl+shift+enter) does it perfectly:

```
=SUM(--(COUNTIF(B$2:B$5,"<"&ROW(A:A))-COUNTIF(C$2:C$5,"<"&ROW(A:A))>0))
```

But i need to tweak it to be able to do it for each machine (there are hundreds of machines)

I saw this formula that calculates for each one (first you fill out rows with unique machine numbers and then it does the calculation, but this only calculates overlapping times

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$36=$I2),--($C$2:$C$36>$B$3:$B$37),--($B$3:$B$37<>""), 
($C$2:$C$36-$B$3:$B$37)-($C$2:$C$36-$C$3:$C$37)*($C$2:$C$36>$C$3:$C$37)* 
($C$3:$C$37<>0))
```

This is column I

```
Machine 1
Machine 2
Machine 3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS and add the criteria for the machine:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,"<"&ROW($A$35000:$A$60000),$A$2:$A$10,I1)-COUNTIFS(C$2:C$10,"<"&ROW($A$35000:$A$60000),$A$2:$A$10,I1)>0))
```

I also limited the number of rows to iterate.  The formula will iterate from `28-Oct-1995` to `8-Apr-2064`.  If those dates are not sufficient then please change the row numbers to match the dates desired.

Using the full column will cause a slow down as each formula will iterate over 2 million times.  these will only iterate a mere 50,000 time for each formula.

[image]

---

EDIT

As explained above we want to limit the iterations.  This formula will automatically limit the iterations to the MIN and MAX dates.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,"<"&ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(B:C)-1):INDEX(A:A,MAX(B:C)+1)),$A$2:$A$10,I1)-COUNTIFS(C$2:C$10,"<"&ROW(INDEX(A:A,MIN(B:C)-1):INDEX(A:A,MAX(B:C)+1)),$A$2:$A$10,I1)>0))
```

Comment: thank you so so much. This absolutely worked. Really grateful. You even made it faster by reducing the number of iterations. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I don't really know so much on excel, please can you explain the correlation between the row numbers and the dates(ROW($A$35000:$A$60000)) & (28-Oct-1995 to 8-Apr-2064) I never really understood what the function of ROW was in the formula. Thanks

Comment: I will really appreciate your help on this

Comment: 35000 is how excel sees `28-oct-1995` it is the number of days since 1/1/1900.  We use the rows to iterate the dates one day at a time.  the more rows that are used the more iterations and the slower the result.  Limit the number of days to the dates and it will be much quicker.  The formula literally goes day by day and test whether it overlaps or not.